# Which version of OJDBC should I use with oracle 12c and 19c

Tags: ojdbc

I am supporting two versions of oracle 12c(12.1.0.2.0) and 19c. Currently I am using ojdbc6:11.1.0.7. I wonder if I should change it to ojdbc8:12.2.0.1, or it does not matter. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The driver is backward compatible. You could even use the driver from 19c.

Comment: I see, but I cannot use ojdbc6 while running oracle 19c am I right? Or it does not really matter.

Comment: Both the client and server are backward compatible up to 2 major releases. So, no, you shouldn't use the 11.1 driver to connect to 19c. The 12c driver is the oldest you should use. You could use the 19c driver to connect to both 12.1 and 19c servers.